# Trying to store json object array in state, then map the items into render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to react.

I am trying to store json object array in state, then map the items into the component render.

I am not sure how to debug this/no console errors either :/

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/XWrLrxX?editors=1111

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
   users: [],
   isLoading: true,
   errors: null
};

getUsers() { 
axios.get("REMOVED")
  .then(response =>
    response.data.results.map(user => ({
      name: `${user.Id}`,
      Company: `${user.Company}`,
    }))
  )
  .then(users => {
    this.setState({
      users,
      isLoading: false
    });
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.getUsers();
}

render() {
const { isLoading, users } = this.state;
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <h2>Random User</h2>
    <div>
      {!isLoading ? (
        users.map(user => {
          const { Company, Id } = user;
          return (
            <div key={Id}>
              <p>{Company}</p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The name of the company should be rendered.

Comment: you don't get response

Comment: it is some error when you do axios.get

Comment: Currently what I can see from the example is that you problem of CORS while calling api. If you own server for `abenzymes.com`, you need to configure it to enable CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking good. I think, you are not getting the expected data. Please try to log your response.

Replace this code:

```
.then(response =>
    response.data.results.map(user => ({
      name: `${user.Id}`,
      Company: `${user.Company}`,
    }))
  )
```

with

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.data.results.map(user => ({
      name: `${user.Id}`,
      Company: `${user.Company}`,
    }))
  })
```

And check the response object in your console.

**Update**

Your code should look like this (when CORS plugin is ON or your server and client are setup such that there is no CORS error):

```
.then(response => 
  response.data.map(user => ({
      name: `${user.Id}`,
      Company: `${user.Company}`,
    }))
  )
```

Comment: 2 objects come back when I use a cors add on in firefox

Comment: @BennKingy I expect one of them is `data`. If so, then make sure that data has `results` directly underneath it and also check if results is an `array`.

Comment: @BennKingy `response.data` is an array in your case. So, you should directly map over it. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @BennKingy I have updated my answer. Please take a look at the Update part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you Vishal. I have this working perfectly now, once I spend a bit more time on these data structures/react debugging I will be a much better react developer.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as written.  You just need to handle the `error` state.

Currently, there is an error when you make the `axios` call:

> {"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain,
>   */*"},"method":"get","url":"https://www.abenzymes.com/umbraco/api/careers/getcareers?siteid=13930"},"request":{}}

You can see it by rendering it out next to the `h2`:

```
render() {
const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <h2>Random User {JSON.stringify(error)}</h2>
    <div>
      {!isLoading ? (
        users.map(user => {
          const { Company, Id } = user;
          return (
            <div key={Id}>
              <p>{Company}</p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the console:

```
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked:
 The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at   https://www.abenzymes.com/umbraco/api/careers/getcareers?siteid=13930.
 (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

You need to add a CORS header to your request and The cors have to be enabled on the server as well.
Links that might help:

- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS